# Python login program doesn't work. The program takes data from txt file and compares password and usernames

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function works if the username and password is correct

```
def work():
    print("SUPER") 

#function login

def login():

#we input pass and username

    input_username = input("input username: ")
    input_password = input("input password: ")

#open file, text is down


    file = open("myfile.txt","r")
    myfile = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    for line in myfile:
        name, lastname, username, password = line.split("/")
            if (input_username == username):
                if (input_password == password):
                    print("BRAVO!")
                    work()
                else:
                    print("NOOOOOOOOO")
                    login()

        login()
```

This is in the file myfile.txt:

```
John/Jin/John007/123456
Janna/Jin/Jannathebest/654321
```

The program takes the data from the file and compares them with entered
the program will not accept the correct username and password
l think that print(line) shows only the first row of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the whitespace and newline characters from the strings that you read in. You can do this using the strip method (str.strip()).

Comment: The problem is most likely in your text file. Can you provide a sample of it?

Comment: it s not problem in text just when i input correct data python dont wont to call(go) in function work.                                            this is in file:                                                   name1/lname1/username1/password1      \n                                                                                                          name2/lname2/username2/password2

Comment: Your wording is somewhat confusing, but I am assuming that correct input is resulting in "NOOOOOOOOO." You define input_username and input_password in the function login(); therefore, they are locally defined variables. That means that the input_username and input_password do not have the actual values in them. In order for the values to be stored, you can either globally define those variables, or you can return them and store them in another variable in your main function.